# How do we override the choice field display of a reference property in appengine using Django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

The default choice field display of a reference property in appengine returns the choices
as the string representation of the entire object. What is the best method to override this behaviour? I tried to override str() in the referenced class. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be to override the `__unicode__` method of the class, like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

where `name` is the value that you want to display.

Comment: That is correct. I think my scenario was a bit different and I don't remember now.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by overriding the init method of the modelform to pick up the correct fields as I had to do filtering of the choices as well.